# "Cannot read property of undefined" NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

This is my NodeJS/Express/Mongoose application.
https://gist.github.com/nosille/e114ed3cb52ed88650c1

[This](https://gist.github.com/nosille/679f67dbd9e9f8dbce65) is my template `register.jade` file that's supposed to receive the `firstName` property from the user object from the main application. I suspect there might be something wrong with the header order, so that the properties of the `user` object aren't sent before the template is rendered.

Comment: Do you generate header different if user present or not? Can you paste code where header renders?